# Can Actors reply, which uses a thread local variable, cause a bug?

Tags: scala, actor

I noticed that `Actor` [reply](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.actors.Actor%24) invokes the `reply` method of a thread local variable of `ReplyReactor` type (see private method`rawSelf`). This `reply` method sends a message to the `senders.head`, where the `senders` is a list of senders (see [the source](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.actors.ReplyReactor)).

Now I wonder if it may cause a bug. What if two actors share one thread with a thread local `ReplyReactor` instance ? Is there a scenario, when one of the actors replies to a wrong sender ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actors do share threads, but they cannot be interrupted. They'll run until the next `react` or end of `loop`, at which point they cannot `reply` anymore, before doing another `react` or `receive`.