# When one should call resetProxy and clearSelf methods of Actor?

Tags: scala, actor

This is a followup of [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065174/can-actors-reply-which-uses-a-thread-local-variable-cause-a-bug). When one should invoke `resetProxy` and `clearSelf`of [Actor](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.actors.Actor$) ? What are they actually useful for?

Answer (score 1):

These methods are used when a "regular" thread ( not threads executing actors ) is talking to an actor. Since there isn't a proper actor sending a message to another actor a proxy actor is instantiated for the thread. You should use the clearSelf method when a thread is long lived and periodically talks to actors especially threads from a thread pool. This method clears the proxy actor created for the thread to have a conversation with other actors so it should be called at the end of an actor dialog. resetProxy is useful when you suspect a proxy actor has died during a dialog and plan to retry.